# Kali Linux image checksum is not valid and fails on boot

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi, kernel-panic, disk-image

Hello World. Don't know if this is the best place to post this, so if it's off-topic, please let me know.

I've got a raspberry pi 4 model B, and I want to install Kali Linux on it. I've also got a 32GB SD card and I've downloaded the corresponding Kali Linux ARM Image. Until here, everything is ok.

Problems start appearing when I try to flash the image to the SD card using [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). It flashes the image but displays an error saying `Checksums are not valid`, and that's not true.

The checksum is `50435f200afcb58be9ad90ba7cfb0bd404ec4a680c794e4fdb3fe456e0001856`, and as indicated on Offensive Security's website, it is correct.

Even if I get to install the image on the SD card using `dd`, I still get the same error when booting.

Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Here you have an image of what it says when booting.

[image]

**Please note I'm new into this kind of thing, so please if this is a stupid question just let me know and I'll delete it. There's no need for downvoting.**

**EDIT**: I've checked [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41965/error-on-boot-no-working-init-found) question on the Raspberry PI Stackexchange, but none of the suggestions work, as they all say it's problem of the root filesystem being somehow corrupted, but that's not the case.

As seen in the logs above, the errors start appearing after the `checksum invalid` log, and I also get the same error on balenaEtcher, that's why I believe the problem is about the checksums being invalid.

I was suggested to use another image but wasn't able to find it, because, as far as I know (or was able to find on the internet), the only image available for the Raspberry PI 4 64-bit is the one I'm using.

Comment: I don't know `balenaEtcher`, but if this program indicates a checksum mismatch, it could simply be a faulty SD card. Try a different SD card if possible.

Comment: @Freddy Ok, I will try another SD card. Thanks for answering! :)